# How can I heal my horse?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

My horse has gotten accidentally hit by things like stray arrows, spear swinging, and a bomb. I know my horse can die because of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302522/how-to-free-a-horse), but how can I *prevent* my horse from dying?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>From [this post](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/632936-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75069418) there are two solutions:</s>

- Feeding the horse
- If the horse is registered at a stable and it dies, you can revive it with a Great Fairy

> Feeding them will heal them at the same rate it heals you. An apple heals half a heart. I have no idea if boarding them helps, or how much max health is.
>
> If it has been registered at a stable then if it dies you can resurrect him using a great fairy

This is the only source I found saying that feeding them actually heals them, so its credibility isn't the best. The Great Fairy option would probably be the best way to get your house back at full health.

**Edit:**

The information previously posted in my answer was from when the game was still fairly new.  In fact, the source I have linked above is from only two days after the game released.

From a comment on my answer, [this thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75364973) points out some ways to actually heal your horse.  They are:

- Boarding the horse
- Fast-Traveling

The author of that thread even includes a YouTube video of them analyzing how horse healing works (see below).  They concluded that feeding them **does not** actually heal the horse, as my answer said.

What the author does is damage their horse a set amount of times, and then tries various ways of healing it.  After attempting to heal it, they see if the amount of damage the horse takes before collapsing is more or not.

Comment: based on this post, feeding doesn't heal a horse at all: https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75364973

Comment: @lI noted.  I've updated my answer.  My old answer was with fresh information from when the game first released.  Video proof is pretty good evidence, so I am concluding that feeding a horse doesn't heal it like I once said.

Answer (score 4):

Feeding them doesn't heal them, just increases bonding level. Boarding them heals them.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fairy called something like "horse god fairy" Im not sure but i think you can ressurect horses from her.

You can find her at "Lake of the horse god-Horse god bridge- Fairy fountain following this bridge.

Said it would cost 1000 rupees to "start her up" and i didnt have that at the point but i belive the cost depends on how many fairy ponds you already activated.

Hope this helps and ill gladly try to answer if there is anything else about this.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet on healing your horse without it dying in the first place is by healing it how you would heal yourself: eating.
Of course, don't just eat in front of the horse yourself. That's just rude. You can drop some food items for it to eat and heal itself with. Maybe hot springs help, as well.

Answer (score 0):

yeah eating definitely helps, I've got Epona so knowing how to heal a horse is important, you can only get her once and the horse god cant revive her if she dies, she only seems to eat after getting struck by something and she'll stop/refuse any more once she's all 'healed up'.

I'm sure all horses do this, they'll eat until they're all healed up and ready to go so just stock up on apples, wont be hard since they're everywhere.